# Can't connect to Jenkins after successfully installing the Helm chart on the Google Cloud Platform

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-helm

On my Google Cloud Platform I have installed a Jenkins helm chart with `helm install --name jenkins stable/jenkins`.

The service is listed on my *Kubernetes services* page with the status *OK*.

However when I access the endpoint the connection times out.
There is no relevant error message in the Docker log.

Installing Artifactory and Drupal via Helm worked without problems.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that our company firewall blocked the port `8080` into the outside world.